# Why can't I call Bokeh file_html on Bar chart?

Tags: python, bokeh

So I have the following code which works great:

```
from bokeh.plotting import circle
from bokeh.resources import CDN 
from bokeh.embed import file_html

plot = circle([1,2], [3,4])

html = file_html(plot, CDN, "my plot")
```

`html` winds up containing an html string which draws a circle. However I can't do the same thing with a `Bar` object.

```
from bokeh.plotting import circle
from bokeh.resources import CDN 
from bokeh.embed import file_html

plot = Bar(OrderedDict(tuples))

html = file_html(plot, CDN, "my plot")
```

This fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./viz.py", line 66, in <module>
    html = file_html(b, CDN, "my plot")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/embed.py", line 120, in file_html
    script, div = components(plot_object, resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/embed.py", line 41, in components
    ref = plot_object.ref
AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'ref'
```

I'm assuming that `Bar` object is not an plot object. How can I turn it in to one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question (with the current Bokeh version 0.7.1) has been answered both [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/bokeh/uUN23e2i3Jg) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051734/bokeh-python-cannot-get-html-source-for-bar-plots-in-bokeh).

Considering your code, the following should work:

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar
from bokeh.resources import CDN 
from bokeh.embed import file_html

plot = Bar(OrderedDict(tuples))
plot.show()
html = file_html(plot.chart.plot, CDN, "my plot")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled across this. For a while now, and definitely in 0.12, the original code should no longer generate an error.